# GridBagLayout and ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, gridbaglayout

Ok, so here's the setup: 
3 components in a panel (a JScrollpane, a JPanel, and a JTabbedPane).

```
this.plan = new JPanel();
this.plan.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

//The ScrollPane
this.SrsDocument = new JTextArea();
this.SrsDocument.setEditable(false);
this.SrsDocumentScroll = new JScrollPane(this.SrsDocument);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 0.33;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
this.plan.add(this.SrsDocumentScroll, c);
...
//The Panel
this.TreePanel = new JPanel();
this.TreePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.TreePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
this.Tree = new JTree();
((DefaultTreeModel)(this.Tree.getModel())).setRoot(null);
this.Tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
this.TreeScroll = new JScrollPane(this.Tree);
this.TreePanel.add(this.TreeScroll);
c.gridx = 1;
c.weightx = 0.33;
this.plan.add(this.TreePanel, c);
...
//The TabbedPane
this.currentFunction = new JTabbedPane();
c.gridx = 2;
c.weightx = 0.33;
this.plan.add(this.currentFunction, c);
```

I had expected this layout to have 3 columns, all with even width. yet the initial display has this.SrsDocumentScroll much narrower in width then the other 2. Additionally, as I resize the window this.SrsDocumentScroll is consumed while the other do not resize till this.SrsDocumentScroll is completely consumed. I had expected all three to resize equally as this.plan resizes. Does weightx not determine how to distribute space when resizing as I had assumed?

I should also add that the contents of the three are: textArea is filled with text, tree as just a root, and tabbed pane has just one tab. The contents of all change dynamically, but that resizing is not the behavior im having troubles with, just the resizing of the window and it consumes (as window shrinks) leftmost->rightmost instead of equally.

EDIT: This is ment to be more of a test, thats why I used 0.33 for my weightx's. the final result is ment to weight more heavily on the tabbedpane then the others. more like (0.25,0.25,0.5) but more manageable then just those values if you folo me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had expected this layout to have 3 columns, all with even width. ...  I had expected all three to resize equally ...

Much will likely depend on the preferredSize, maximumSize and minimumSize of the components added to the GridBagLayout. If you want equal sized components in 3 columns, don't use a GridBagLayout but rather a `GridLayout(1, 3)` (for 1 row, 3 columns) or `GridLayout(0, 3)` (for 3 columns and variable number of rows).

To show you what I mean, run the code below, commenting or uncommenting these two lines:

```
      // setSizes(btn, scrollpane);
      // setSizes(label, scrollpane);
```

GridBagTest.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

      JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);

      JButton btn = new JButton("Foo");

      JLabel label = new JLabel("Bar");
      label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Bar"));

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;

      panel.add(scrollpane, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      panel.add(btn, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 2;
      panel.add(label, gbc);

      // **** comment or uncomment the lines below
      // setSizes(btn, scrollpane);
      // setSizes(label, scrollpane);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GBC Test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   private static void setSizes(Component changeComponent,
         Component templateComponent) {
      changeComponent.setPreferredSize(templateComponent.getPreferredSize());
      changeComponent.setMaximumSize(templateComponent.getMaximumSize());
      changeComponent.setMinimumSize(templateComponent.getMinimumSize());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is ment to be more of a test, thats why I used 0.33 for my weightx's. the final result is ment to weight more heavily on the tabbedpane then the others. more like (0.25,0.25,0.5) if you folo me. I probably shoulda mentioned that. Thanks

Comment: @Billium813: and GridBagLayout will fail that test. Again, you're not accounting for preferredSize and other attributes of the components being added to the container.

Comment: As a follow up question, why doesnt it behave like a gridlayout with these params? now that you mention it, shouldnt these numbers copy that behavior?

Comment: When I set the preferredSize of this.SrsDocumentScroll, it doesnt seem to make any difference. Do I have to set preferredSize of the textArea? EDIT: changing textArea dimensions does nothing too.

Comment: Ok, so the point is to make sure they are all at the same sizes? I thought setting maxsize and minsize to the same values resulted in a static component. This helps, but im still lost as to if I dont want them all the same size.

Comment: No, I don't recommend they all be the same size as my code is for demonstration purposes only. The point is that setting relative sizes is not as easy as it seems. The ultimate point though is that your requirements will drive what you do be it fiddle with the GBL settings or use an entirely different layout such as MiGLayout.

Comment: well if the point was to show how complicated setting sizes is then you are 100% correct lol. PrefSize, MinSize, and Max Size are three swing methods that have eluded me since I started learning swing. Thanks for the help.